# Hide the path in website URL using PHP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have no idea of URL coding, please help me out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ users.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ users.php?user=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
```

Comment: You need to present your question clearly if you are expecting a helpful answer....

Comment: Hiding the complete path in the url section on reloading / redirecting to other pages, using php

Comment: Update your question and add some clearly defined examples of what you are trying to achieve. it sounds like a simple URL rewrite, but from what to what.....

Comment: What you are showing is an Apache configuration file. This has nothing to do with PHP, but everything with your web server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from php you can use a rewrite rule from your .htaccess file to pass everything to index.php

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And after that you can get $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] that contains the current path (if you want to do something with it) and redirect back to your domain.

```
header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]");
```